Post vs central determiners


Several/certain people came here.
Two/three points are important.


Why are several, certain and cardinal numbers (one, two, three...) considered post-determiners? Why not central determiners as these are used as main determiners?

Because they can be preceded by "a", "the", etc, while "a", "the", etc, can't. This probably belongs on English Language and Usage though. Have you looked at any grammar books/websites, because most seem to explain this quite clearly?

Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?

post-determiner = positioned after determiner
ex) a few boys = a (determiner); few (post determiner); boys (noun)
determiner = words(a, my, the, etc.) that modify noun
In your example, there is no determiner; so they were used as determiners which modify nouns—people, points.
